# Python: Database listener. Periodical checking

Tags: python, django

The program below check the Job table where status is **0** then change the value to **1**, if nothing is found it **sleeps for 5 sec** then check for new entries. The program works fine but I am worried about my solution, if it can runs for how many days non-stop without any problem. I am thinking if its better to implement it using a listener. Any suggestion on how to implement it? Thanks guys!

```
import time
from apps.models.joblist import Jobs

def start_jobs():
  try:
    j = Jobs.objects.filter(status=0)[0]
    #do some job here
    j.status = 1
    j.save()

    Jobs.objects.update()
    start_jobs()
  except Exception as error:
    time.sleep(5)
    start_jobs()
```

Comment: Have you considered using celery [periodic tasks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#periodic-tasks)?

Comment: Who is updating this table? If it is done through the django ORM, you may be interested by signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/

Comment: @luc new entries come from client who encoded new jobs. thanks. i'll check signals.

Comment: @rechie yeah, signals sounds really like a correct way to behave in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use Celery for periodic tasks. Its the most commonly used extension for tasks like this, and there is plenty of good documentation.

You can learn more about it [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).